# Reading csv in loop stops at row that does not match

Tags: python, csv, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to read a csv then iterate through an sde to find matching features, their fields, and then print them.
There is a table in the list and I'm not able to skip over it and continue reading the csv.
I get the "IOError: table 1 does not exist" and I only get the features that come before the table.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import sys
import os
import csv

with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/features_to_look_for.csv', 'r') as t1:
    objectsinESRI = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(t1)]

env.workspace = "//conn/features@dev.sde"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('sometext.*')

for fcs in objectsinESRI:
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fcs)
    for field in fieldList:
        print fcs + " " + ("{0}".format(field.name))
```

Sample csv rows (can't seem to post a screenshot of the excel file)

```
feature 1
feature 2
feature 3
feature 4
table 1
feature 5
feature 6
feature 7
feature 8
feature 9
```

Result

```
feature 1
feature 2
feature 3
feature 4
```

Desired Result

```
feature 1
feature 2
feature 3
feature 4
feature 5
feature 6
feature 7
feature 8
feature 9
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fcs)

Comment: Then (not much knowledge of arcpy here though) suspicious things to look at:

First you are overwritting fcs:
a) fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('sometext.*')

b) for fcs in objectsinESRI:

Comment: As said, no expert here but your code looks quite suspicious (re-writing the fcs variable without using it when getting the ListFeatureClasses) and quite different to what is done here in the documentation in the last example:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/es/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm

Comment: I see what you're saying. I am not sure how to write the loop to look in the csv file and get what matches out of feature class list.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/315407/115

Answer (score 0):

So as stated, I have no clue about arcpy but this seems the way so start. Looking at [the docs](http://desktop.arcgis.com/es/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm), your objectsInEsri seems to be the equivalent of the datasets in the example. From there I extrapolate the following code which, depending on what print(fc) is printing, you may need to extend with yet another for.

So try this:

```
for object in objectsInEsri:
    for fc in fcs:
        print(fc)
```

Or maybe this:

```
for object in objectsInEsri:
    for fc in fcs:
        for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc)
            print(object + " " + ("{0}".format(field.name)))
```

Then I may be completely wrong ofc but then just write first the outermore for, see what is giving to you, and keep building from there :)